# Redirect user to a path depending on his role with Laravel-Spatie

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

Laravel-8 with the Spatie permission package. I have already assigned role and permissions to my users. My problem is how can I route my users after logging in to a path according to their role?

I have the following roles: Admin, Manager, Administrative, Teacher, Student. I want your route to be something like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'verified', 'role:Admin']], function() {
  // ...
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'manager', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'verified', 'role:Manager']], function() {
  // ...
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'teacher', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'verified', 'role:Teacher']], function() {
  // ...
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'student', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'verified', 'role:Student']], function() {`
  // ...
});
```

Comment: what are you using to do the login?

Answer (score 0):

[hi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMb9w.png)

[an example is ready for you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ng0t.png)

Answer (score 0):

In HomeController add this in the index method:

```
public function index()
{
    $userCurrent = \auth()->user()->getRoleNames()->first();
    
    if ($userCurrent === \auth()->user()->hasRole('Directivo')) {
        return redirect('dirtvo/dashboard');
    } else if ($userCurrent === \auth()->user()->hasRole('Administrativo')) {
        return redirect('/adtvo/dashboard');
    } else if ($userCurrent === \auth()->user()->hasRole('Docente')) {
        return redirect('/prof/dashboard');
    } else if ($userCurrent === \auth()->user()->hasRole('Estudiante')) {
        return redirect('/est/dashboard');
    } else {
        return redirect('/adm/dashboard');
    }
    #return view('home');
}
```